# Router with speed controls?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, speed, bandwidth

Is there a router that I could purchase to control speeds allocated to each MAC Address in my house?

Comment: Look for routers with good QoS support, that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the following firmware:

- [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com)
- [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)
- [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, buy a router that supports [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/). They have a list of supported routers.